# calculate the sum of line items depending on condition in XSLT

Tags: xslt-1.0

I need to calculate the Gross weight by adding Weight+Count of each line. But i need to check
Level segment in each item.
If item has single level  - Level=1 i should add both Weight+Count. But if item has multi-
level - Level=1 and Level=2 both then it should take only weight.

In the sample XML first item is single-level and second item is multi-level. So total should
be
<1st item> - (10+4)+(10+4)+(10+4)
<2nd item> - 10+10+20+20+20
Total Gross weight = 122

Is it possible to to consider each line with the above condition and add the total Gross
weight. I'm really not finding any way to achieve this.
If any possible solution for this kindly help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Main>
<Item>
  <Line>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Weight>10</Weight>
    <Count>4</Count>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Weight>10</Weight>
    <Count>4</Count>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Weight>10</Weight>
    <Count>4</Count>
  </Line>
</Item>

<Item>
  <Line>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Weight>10</Weight>
    <Count>8</Count>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Level>1</Level>
    <Weight>10</Weight>
    <Count>8</Count>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Weight>20</Weight>
    <Count>10</Count>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Weight>20</Weight>
    <Count>10</Count>
  </Line>
  <Line>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Weight>20</Weight>
    <Count>10</Count>
  </Line>
</Item>
</Main>
```

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
        >
    
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="Main" >   
        <root>
         <xsl:call-template name="Template1">
             <xsl:with-param name="NodeList" select="Item/Line"/>    
         </xsl:call-template>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    
    <xsl:template  name ="Template1">  
        <xsl:param name="NodeList" />
        
        
        <xsl:for-each select="$NodeList">
            <Group>
                <xsl:value-of select="(Weight)+(Count)" />
             </Group>
        </xsl:for-each>  
        
     </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you sure about your logic? I would have thought that the total weight is the sum of `Weight * Count` of each `Line`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Main">
    <result>
        <xsl:call-template name="process-items">
            <xsl:with-param name="items" select="Item"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="process-items">
    <xsl:param name="items"/>
    <xsl:param name="total" select="0"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$items">
            <xsl:variable name="item" select="$items[1]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="amount">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="not($item/Line/Level != $item/Line/Level)">
                    <!-- single level -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum($item/Line/Weight) + sum($item/Line/Count)" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                    <!-- multi-level -->
                        <xsl:value-of select="sum($item/Line/Weight)"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="process-items">
                <xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]" />
                <xsl:with-param name="total" select="$total + $amount" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$total"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The other way has been shown in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70055358/3016153): calculate the individual item values in a variable, then sum the results.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. But in my case level=1 can repeat multiple times for single level and also for multi-level level=1,level=2 can be multiple times. For simplicity i shown only 2 levels but i have till 9 levels and it needs to be grouped single and multi-level. While trying for my scenario i am unable to do AND condition (<xsl:when test="$item/Line[Level='1']!='' and $item/Line[Level='2']!=''">) this is repeating twice to say values are summing twice instead of 2 it is showing 4

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Please edit your question and show a better example.

Comment: I have changed the XML and added more segments. So in single level we will have unique level=1, but for multi-level we will have both level=1&level=2

Comment: I am still not sure what exactly is the difference between "single level" and "multi-level". Does  "single level" mean that all Lines in an Item have the same level -regardless of which level it is?

Comment: I have  edited my answer based on the above assumption. The result for your example is 122, as stated in your question. HTH.

Comment: Your answer for both of my issues (current and previous question) helped me solve my business case. I am very delighted. Many thanks for your effort and patience .